# What is the distribution of linear model parameters?

Tags: regression, distributions, normal-distribution, linear-model

I am interested in testing if linear models are statistically different, so I would like to know what I can assume about the distribution of linear parameter models, like the slope for example.

More specifically, assume I randomly sample n $(x,y)$ pairs from a random source, and perform a linear regression on these values. What will the distribution of the resulting slope and intercept be?

Thanks!

Comment: The small-sample sampling distribution depends on the distribution of $y$, and on whether the other assumptions of regression are satisfied. Under the usual assumptions, [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/60097/805) answer covers it (see the later part). If the distribution of $y$ is non-normal, you (often) still have asymptotic normality. If the other regression assumptions are violated, things get more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OLS, which would probably be the BLUE estimator for the problem in your questions and given small sample assumptions (See, for example, Hayashi- Econometrics A1 to A5) we have
$$Y=\alpha + \beta X + \epsilon\\
V[\epsilon|X]=\sigma^2 \\ (etc...)\\$$
So that
$$
Y|X \sim U N(\alpha + \beta X, \sigma^2) \\
\hat{\beta}_{OLS} \sim N ( \beta, \frac{\sigma^2}{nV[X]}) \\
\hat{\alpha}_{OLS} \sim N ( \alpha, \sigma^2\frac{\sum x_i^2}{n^2V[X]})$$

Comment: Since you said randomly sampled from a (bivariant) normal distribution, you'll have an i.i.d.N $(y,x)$ sample. If the linear model holds as specified, this also makes sure that $(x,\epsilon)$ is iid N and then we basically have what we need for those assumptions. So with that in this rare case it would be allowed to just run with the basic OLS results and do all the F-Testing you like without worry :)

Comment: Actually I didn't say that but the person who edited my question made it look like it. Anyways, thanks for your answers and both cases are interesting.